# IntelliJ Idea 12 CANNOT run/deploy web application

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a java application with web module set up in IntelliJ 12. I am trying to run my application from the IDE. However, everytime I hit the run button I get this error

```
Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason:
           java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
           java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]
```

I get the following output as well:

```
    [2014-02-07 05:42:22,126] Artifact arisk.dashboard:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
    Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\.IntelliJIdea12\system\tomcat\Unnamed_AtlasRisk"
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apps\apache\jakarta\tomcat\"
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apps\apache\jakarta\tomcat\temp"
    Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07"
    Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\apps\apache\jakarta\tomcat\\bin\bootstrap.jar"
    Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
               (to execute a class)
       or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
               (to execute a jar file)
    where options include:
        -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
        -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
        -client   to select the "client" VM
...
    See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
    Disconnected from server
```

I am using the following configuration

[image]

Any idea why is this not running? THANKS

Comment: It's difficult to give concert answer, but it seams tomcat problem accrued. Extract a new tomcat copy and try again instead of current.

Comment: BTW have you clicked `+` before configuring?

Comment: Yes I did... that is required

Comment: Why is your `$CATALINA_HOME` different from `$CATALINA_BASE`? Could you please try to create new Tomcat configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi and downloaded a new version of tomcat, pointed my IDE to it and my problems were gone. It looks like I had tomcat 5.x and Intellij Idea 12 doesn't like it.

It look like Intellij Idea 12 require support for JNI based application which Tomcat 5.x doesn't have.